# GUI Interface class

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to make a method that makes a call from a Mobile Phone class which should be a functional button in a GUI. When the phone number and the duration of the call are entered in the GUI,the method to get the display number is called and its value is checked. Anyone got ideas on how to write the makeCall() method? So far I've done this -

```
public int getDisplayNumber()
    {
        int displayNumber = -1;

        try {
            displayNumber
              = Integer.parseInt(DisplayNumberTextbox.getText());
            if(displayNumber < 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, 
                   "Please enter a positive number");
            }
            else if(displayNumber > numberOfGadgets()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, 
                   "Please enter a number in the correct range");
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException exception) {
        }
        return displayNumber;
    }

     public void makeCall()
    {
        int displayNumber = getDisplayNumber();
        MobilePhone mobile = (MobilePhone) item.get(displayNumber);
    }
```

Comment: As per your code, you are calling the `makeCall()` method inside the `new MobilePhone( makeCall() )`. But the method return type for `makeCall()` is void and I assume constructor in `MobilePhone` class expects an argument. Can you post how your `MobilePhone` class look like

Comment: https://ibb.co/YprnSCN

Comment: There is a constructor argument mismatch

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.